# Double End of Line characters in Google and Delete them

Tags: google-apps-script

As part of a App I'm writing, I need to produce a letter . The letter is effectively a mail merge . The problem I'm having is in the address section. We have fields for Address1 & Address 2 and City1 and City2, where there is a blank field it leaves a blank line. I'm trying to find a way to delete the blank line. The blank lines are showing as double end of line character, but I can't get the routine to work

Here is my code

```
function deleteDoubleParagraphAndResave(documentId) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(documentId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();
  
  // Replace instances of two consecutive end-of-paragraph characters with a single end-of-paragraph character
  var newText = text.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
  
  // Update the document content with the modified text
  body.setText(newText);
  
  // Save and close the document
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong (this is a ChatGpt solution but I'd also wrote a similar routine separately, both failed)  I should also add the scripts completed but didn't remove the EoL characters

Many thanks

Comment: Are you sure that it's not `\r\n` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
var newText = text.replace(/\n{1,}/g, '\n');
```

I always use the regex tester  [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)